# @Inject on field gives NullPointerException in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have class `MyTransformer` which uses:

`ZonedDateTime currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(generator.generate(), polishZone);`

generator is interface:

```
public interface Generator {
    Instant generate();
}
```

and it's injected into `MyTransformer`:

```
public class MyTransformer {
    @Inject                                      
    private Generator Generator;
```

The real implementation is in another class:

```
public class DateTimeGenerator implements Generator {
    @Override
    public Instant generate() {
        return Instant.now();
    }
}
```

However when I try to `new MyTransformer()` from test class I always see that Generator is `null`. In my MainModule I have `bind(Generator.class).to(DateTimeGenerator.class)`. Is it possible to inject `Generator` on field? I can inject it in constructor and then it works.

Comment: "*I can inject it in constructor and then it works*" Constructor injection is better anyway. Why not just use that?

Comment: It's called by service which I am not owner and it MUST have default constructor ;/

Comment: The no-arg constructor is called by that external service? If they are instantiating this thing directly, they are operating outside of the DI framework, so of course nothing will be injected

Comment: @Michael, I am also calling it in Test class and in debug I see it's always `null`. The problem is somewhere else which I actually can't find.

Comment: If you **ever** call `new MyTransformer`, nothing will be injected. You need to let Guice handle the construction. The best way to ensure an object is not created with invalid state (i.e. null fields thanks to field injection) is to use constructor injection.